# Displaying dictionary value in django template

Tags: python, django, templates

All,

I have the following in my views.py

```
def getgradeform(request):
   id1=request.user.get_pf().id
   sc=Sc.objects.filter(id=id1)
   logging.debug(sc)
   logging.debug("++++")
   dict={}
   dict.update({'sc': sc})
   return render_to_response('content/add.html',dict)
```

Logging.debug gives an output as `[<sc: Robert>]`

My question is that how do i display Robert in the template .

I have tried the following in the template:`<input type ="text" value={{sc}}/> //This gives me the dictionary itself`

`<input type ="text" value={{dict.sc}}/> //This also doesnt work.`

Thanks......

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want any value in a dictionary, you have to do it on the way

```
dict.key
```

(On python you'll write it as dict['key'])

So, to present the value stored with key 'name'

```
{{ sc.name }}
```

Anyway, I think this is not you're case. I think you're not seeing a dictionary, but an object defined from models (as is a entry on the database).
You're storing in `dict` (don't call that value as `dict` , you're masking a keyword) a key 'sc' with value variable `sc`, which is returned from a model. I'm having to guess, because I don't know how this model is. Maybe 'Robert' is stored in the attribute `name`, `id` or something similar?

You need to show then the proper attribute, something like

```
{{ sc.name }}
{{ sc.id }}
```

Comment: Thanks but i still have problems displaying it........
Logging.debug gives an output as [<SC: Robert>](sorry not small case sc) and when i say {{sc.SC}} the output is null

Comment: I figured it out thanks for the help.I used a for loop to display the value like the following {% for s in sc %} {{ s }} {% endfor %}

Comment: OK, then you wanted to print all the values on the dictionary ;-)